# Xcode C++ Undeclared Identifier Error

Tags: c++

I have created a class in a header file and have listed a `int rsvdtickets` in the `private` section of the class. When trying to use this member in a function in the same header file (I am trying to add ticket prices so I am wanting to save the total under this `int rsvdtickets`), the compiler throws an undeclared identifier error.

I've made sure the spelling is all correct, but I am not sure how to fix this problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

class tickets
{
public:
   void getheldtickets();
   void computeseats();
   void availabetickets();

private:
   int rsvdtickets;
   int availtickets;  
};


void getheldtickets()
{
   int seasontkt;
   int corptkt;

   std::cout << "How many season ticket holders?";
   std::cin >> seasontkt;
   std::cout << "How many reserved corporate ticket holders?";
   std::cin >> corptkt;

   rsvdtickets = seasontkt + corptkt;  
}
```

Comment: We need to see the actual code.

Comment: `void tickets::getheldtickets()`

Comment: Your function isn't in scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you have:

```
void getheldtickets()
{
    // ..
    rsvdtickets = seasontkt + corptkt;
}
```

You're not defining `tickets::getheldtickets`, you're actually declaring and defining an entirely unrelated free function called `getheldtickets`. That function is unrelated to the class `tickets`, and thus has no access to the `tickets` members - and so `rsvdtickets` is an declared identifier.

The correct way to define a class method external to the class is:

```
void tickets::getheldtickets()
//   ^^^^^^^^^
{
    // everything as before
}
```